# Can I trigger on ZBX_NOTSUPPORTED with Zabbix?

Tags: monitoring, zabbix

I'm trying to check if my configuration management system is running on my servers. It is pretty easy to use it to distribute a Zabbix configuration that will test if the CMS is running. However, hosts that are not presently running the CMS will return ZBX_NOTSUPPORTED, and I'd like to detect these as well.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set an item **zabbix[items_unsupported]**, then make a trigger if returned value of this item > 0.

Check the list of [internal checks](http://www.zabbix.com/documentation/1.8/complete#internal_checks) in the documentation for more information.

Comment: This won't tell me if my one particular item is unsupported.

Comment: Unsupported items are bad, for any item...

Comment: If you really want to check unsupported item for particular item anyway, you can try to get it from zabbix_server.log with "logrt[file_format,<regexp>,<encoding>,<maxlines>,<mode>]"

Answer (score 1):

You can set a log trigger to read zabbix server log searching by 'cms item' and 'ZBX_NOTSUPPORTED', but, if you had zabbix agent installed on machines without CMS installed, you can search by cms user or try read CMS logs in Zabbix.

This key should work for puppet and Debian: 'vfs.file.regmatch[/etc/passwd,puppet]'

Answer (score 1):

Go here:  http://www.zabbix.com/forum/showpost.php?p=85153&postcount=7

One bright spark created an external script for use in zabbix that will tell you server by server which items are unsupported.

Easy to install and easy to make work.

This will solve your problem where the zabbix[items_unsupported] will not.

Answer (score 1):

For any people still wondering, unsupported item notification is now supported since Zabbix 2.2 and involves creating a specific Action (not an Item), and include all details concerning the unsupported item in the notification.

The complete procedure is described in the [Zabbix official documentation](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/2.2/manual/config/notifications/unsupported_item).